# NodeJS https request failing with Error: socket hang up - code: ECONNRESET - failing on AWS EC2 but working perfectly locally on MacOS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, https

I am using this code to connect to a 3rd party server via HTTP GET. Locally on my MacOS this script works perfectly and I get statusCode:200 together with a valid message from the server. Am I missing something which should be added to this request when connecting from AWS?

```
const https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");

var httpsAgent = require("https-agent");

var agent = httpsAgent({
    pfx: fs.readFileSync("certs/test.com.pfx"),
    passphrase: "xxxxxx",
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    //enableTrace: true,
    ca: fs.readFileSync("certs/ca-bundle.pem"),
});

const path = "/testapp?application=TEST&method=send&message=TEST"

const options = {
    hostname: "test.server.com",
    port: 443,
    path: path,
    method: "GET",
    agent: agent,
};
''

console.log("Connecting to: https://test.server.com" + path)

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

    res.on("data", (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});

req.on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(error);
});

req.end();
```

Comment: I have also tested app on windows and also worked. Seems like issue is related to AWS

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved: Issue was actually not related to SSL. Packet was being reject to invalid MTU size. Adjusted MTU value and worked as expected.